# Predicting any Value from the Model using the Predict Function R

Tags: r

I have developed a simple linear regression model by having some training data and then predicting some new or testing data.

```
regressor = lm(formula=Discount ~ Bill, data = trainingData) 
y_pred1 = predict(regressor,newdata = testingData)
```

Now i want to use the same for predicting some other new value. Here is what i am trying

```
pred_discount = predict(regressor, newdata=84)
```

But it throws the following Error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : not that many frames on the stack
```

Then i searched on Google and StackOverflow and come to know that i should do something like this

```
pred_discount = predict(regressor, newdata = data.frame(x=64))
```

But this is also not working..Maybe the same type of question was answered many years ago and now this method is also not working.. Here is what the error i am getting

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Bill' not found
```

What i am getting wrong? It is also worth mentioning that Bill is my independent variable in my dataset

Comment: Try `pred_discount = predict(regressor, newdata = data.frame(Bill=64))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you discovered is that when you use the formula interface, you have to supply a named data frame to the function. That is the test data frame needs to have the same structure / column names as the training set. You can either create a data frame outside the predict function and the pass it to predict, or create a data frame inside the predict function (not recommended), this would be done only if, as in your case, you have a very small data frame which you want to predict.

So something like

```
testData=data.frame(Bill=c(1,2,3,4,5))
pred_discount = predict(regressor, newdata = testData)
```

Or for new variables

```
testData=data.frame(Bill=c(1,2,3,4,5),Rate=c(1,2,3,4,5))
pred_discount = predict(regressor, newdata = testData)
```